# How to disable trailing space warning in sublimelinter

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin, sublimelinter

I am using SublimeLinter in sublime text 3. I want SublimeLinter to ignore trailing space warning as I've set

```
"trim_trailing_white_space_on_save": true
```

I dont like the red color warning while I am writing. It is distracting me.

I tried this in sublimelinter user settings

```
"jshint_options": {
        "trailing": false
    },
```

as mentioned [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19711921/configuring-sublimelinter-to-ignore-trailing-whitespace)

and also

```
"trailing": false,
```

in every linter (`csslint, jshint, json, php`) setting block separately, but no use. I am still getting annoying red color warning while writhing code.

anyone please help me.